# How to show text on Entry on Tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to make a simple calculator with GUI. So what I have so far are the buttons and the Entry box setup but I have no idea how to display text on them. So Currently, the "equation" is equal to 0. What I want to do is when the user presses the equal button, it would display the solved equation to the Entry called inputbox. What will I have to do to display the equation back to the inputbox?

```
import sys
from Tkinter import *

#modules
equation = '0'

def Entrybox():
    theinput = inputbox.get()
    if type(theinput) is float:
        pass

    elif type(theinput) is int:
        equation += theinput

    else:
        return 'Numbers Only'

def bp1():
    equation = equation + '1'

def bp2():
    equation = equation + '2'

def bp3():
    equation = equation + '3'

def bp4():
    equation = equation + '4'

def bp5():
    equation = equation + '5'

def bp6():
    equation = equation + '6'

def bp7():
    equation = equation + '7'

def bp8():
    equation = equation + '8'

def bp9():
    equation = equation + '9'

def bp0():
    equation = equation + '0'

def bpplus():
    equation = equation + '+'

def bpmin():
    equation = equation + '-'

def bpmulti():
    equation = equation + '*'

def bpdiv():
    equation = equation + '/'

def bpequal():
    eval(equation)
    return 

def bpclear():
    equation = equation - equation


gui = Tk()

inputvar = StringVar()

#gui Size
gui.geometry('360x400')

#title
gui.title("A Lucas Calculator")

#The input box
inputbox = Entry(gui, textvariable = inputvar, bd = 10,width = 34)
inputbox.place(x = 40, y = 50)

#buttons
number3 = Button(gui, text = '3',font = 15,width = 4,command = bp3)
number3.place(x = 200,y = 260)

number2 = Button(gui, text = '2',font = 15,width = 4,command = bp2)
number2.place(x = 120,y = 260)

number1 = Button(gui, text = '1',font = 15,width = 4, command = bp1)
number1.place(x = 40,y = 260)

number6 = Button(gui, text = '6',font = 15,width = 4,command = bp6)
number6.place(x = 200,y = 200)

number5 = Button(gui, text = '5',font = 15,width = 4,command = bp5)
number5.place(x = 120 ,y = 200)

number4 = Button(gui, text = '4',font = 15,width = 4,command = bp4)
number4.place(x = 40, y = 200)

number9 = Button(gui, text = '9',font = 15,width = 4, command = bp9)
number9.place(x = 200,y = 140)

number8 = Button(gui, text = '8',font = 15,width = 4,command = bp8)
number8.place(x = 120,y = 140)

number7 = Button(gui, text = '7',font = 15,width = 4,command = bp7)
number7.place(x = 40,y = 140)

number0 = Button(gui, text = "0",font = 15,width = 4,command = bp0)
number0.place(x = 120,y = 318)

signplus = Button(gui, text = "+", font = 14, width = 3,bg = 'red', fg = 'white',command = bpplus)
signplus.place(x = 280,y = 140)

signmin = Button(gui, text = "-", font = 14, width = 3,command = bpmin)
signmin.place(x = 280,y = 200)

signmulti = Button(gui, text = "X", font = 14, width = 3,command = bpmulti)
signmulti.place(x = 280,y = 260)

signdiv = Button(gui, text = "/", font = 14, width = 3,command = bpdiv)
signdiv.place(x = 280,y = 318)

signequal = Button(gui, text = "=", font = 15, width = 4,bg = 'blue',fg = 'white',command = bpequal)
signequal.place(x = 200, y = 318)

clearbutton = Button(gui, text = "Clear", font = 14, width = 4,bg = "green", fg = "white",command = bpclear)
clearbutton.place(x= 40, y = 318)

gui.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please show us a complete (stripped-down, but runnable) sample. If you do that, we can (a) run your code to figure out what you're talking about if it's not clear, and (b) show how you exactly where to edit your code so that it works for you on the first try. See [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for more.

Comment: Also, I doubt you want to create a new `inputbox`, replacing the old one, every time the user types anything. Unless you're doing some kind of clever entry stack thing?

Comment: I don't think you guys understand my question so I just decided to put the whole code on it.... I want to be about to return the text 'numbers only' back to the inputbox which is a Entry.

Comment: Please read the SSCCE link. Give us a stripped-down version of the code, with just enough stuff to make it runnable, not the entire thing.

Comment: Also, my answer already does exactly what you're trying to do, and explains it. You happen to have _other_ bugs in your `Entrybox` function that prevent you from even getting that far, which I can explain in an edit to my answer, but that's a separate problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've already attached a `textvariable` to the `Entry`, the easiest thing to do is to use it:

```
inputvar.set('numbers only')
```

The tutorial on [The Variable Classes](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) in the Tkinter book explains in more detail… but there's really not much more to explain.

(I'm assuming `inputvar` was properly created as a `Tkinter.StringVar()` somewhere in the code you haven't shown us, and that you're keeping it around somewhere, like an instance variable, for later use. If not, obviously you'd need to fix those things.)

---

If you *weren't* using a `textvariable`, see the [Entry](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm) docs for details on other ways to do it.

---

Unfortunately, your code function as written is too broken to actually get this far.

---

First, the `Entrybox` function that you defined never gets called, so nothing you do in that function can possibly have any effect. I'm not sure where you *wanted* it to get called, so I can't fix that for you.

---

And there's nowhere you *can* actually put such a call, because all of your event handler functions will raise an exception as soon as you click them, because they all look like this:

```
equation = equation + '1'
```

Whenever you assign to a variable in a function, that means it's a local variable, unless you explicitly say otherwise. But you don't *have* a local variable named `equation` until after this assignment finishes—and yet you're trying to use `equation + '1'` as the value. So, you will get `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'equation' referenced before assignment`.

You really shouldn't be using global variables in the first place (a GUI frame is one of the paradigm use cases for a class, which is why all of the non-trivial Tkinter examples are written that way, and you should follow those examples). If you really want to use globals, you can, but then you need to be explicit, like this:

```
def bp1():
    global equation
    equation = equation + '1'
```

---

Meanwhile, once you figure out where and how to call `Entrybox`, there are a number of problems with it:

```
def Entrybox():
    theinput = inputbox.get()
    if type(theinput) is float:
        pass

    elif type(theinput) is int:
        equation += theinput

    else:
        return 'Numbers Only'
```

If you've got an `inputvar`, you really should be using `inputvar.get()`, not going straight to the `Entry`. As written, it won't cause any *problems*, but it makes your code harder to follow.

More seriously, `Entry.get` always returns a string,* so that `theinput` can *never* be an int or a float. So, your comparisons make no sense. And even if they *did* make sense, that's not the way to check types in Python—use `isinstance(theinput, int)`, not `type(theinput)`. And if you really need to compare types (which is very rare), you should use `==`, not `is`. In general, if you don't know which one you want, you want `==`; only use `is` for specific idiomatic cases (like `is None`), or when you want to check that two expressions name the exact same object, not just that they have the same value.

Anyway, if you want to check whether the string in `inputvar` is a string that could be converted to an int, the way to do that is:

```
try:
    value = int(theinput)
    equation += theinput
except:
    return 'Numbers Only'
```

And all of the same things apply for `float`, of course.

---

Once you fix all of those problems, and any others I didn't spot from a cursory glance, *then* you can change that `return 'Numbers Only'` to `inputvar.set('Numbers Only')`, and you're done.

---

However, there's a much, much better design for this whole thing. Just make each of the buttons insert a character onto the end of the Entry, and use the Entry's contents (which you can get from `inputvar`) as the equation, and use either [Entry validation or StringVar tracing](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/12/tkinter-validation.html) to handle illegal key entries. There's an example in that blog post, and another example in the official `Entry` docs linked above.

---

* Actually, it may be either kind of string—`str` or `unicode`—but let's ignore that.

Comment: Thanks for the super long reply. This is my first time I ever created a python program ( if you can tell :D) Well, besides the float and the integer problem, I still don't know how to display text onto the inputbox...... The purpose of the Entrybox is just to return back THROUGH the inputbox and display it on the entry..... Thanks again for going over call of duty but I still don't know how to return a string or text back to the Entry and display it on the GUI.

Comment: @user3150197: I don't know how to explain this any better. All you have to do is `inputvar.set('Numbers Only')`, and that string will display in the GUI, in the Entry. Just try it and see. If you want to have `Entrybox` return a string, and have whoever _calls_ it display it on the GUI, that's just as easy—leave the `return` alone, and change the code so that the caller calls `inputvar.set` with the returned value. (But make sure to return something in the non-error cases!)

Comment: @user3150197: Anyway, your basic design doesn't make sense, in multiple ways. The buttons don't do anything visible (even if you fix the error), whatever the user types into the entry box has no effect (even if you get the validation working), … You'd be a lot better served following a tutorial or some simple examples than trying to design and build a GUI app from scratch as your very first project.

Comment: The buttons aren't supposed to do anything yet.....  I wish I would have done that but its too late for me.... Its a school project xD